# Flask app.after_request() keeps user on the same page

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code:

```
@app.after_request
def sense_inactive(response):
    if session.has_key('usercode'): ## if user has logged in
    usercode = session['usercode']
    inactive_rmt = info.find_one({'usercode': usercode})['inactive']

    curr_time = time.time()
    last_req = session['req_time']
    ## time_difference = datetime.combine(date.today(), curr_time) - datetime.combine(date.today(), last_req)
    time_difference = curr_time - last_req
    if time_difference > 60:
        usercode = session['usercode']
        insert = {'inactive': True}
        info.update_one({'usercode': usercode}, {'$set': insert})
        print 'user is inactive'
    else:
        usercode = session['usercode']
        insert = {'inactive': False}
        info.update_one({'usercode': usercode}, {'$set': insert})


   else: ## if user hasn't logged in

   return response
```

...that I'm attempting to use to determine whether or not a user is 'active' on my web app. However, running this code makes all links revert back to the same page; I click on a link, and the app.after_request code runs, but the page stays the same.

Is my 'return response' line causing the problem? I've read in some (somewhat cryptic) documentation that app.after_request decorated functions need parameters in order to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code actually looks like this:

```
if 'usercode' in session:
    ...
else:  # if user hasn't logged in
    return response
```

You're only returning a response if the user is not logged in.  Remove the `else` and always return the response whether you do something else or not.

```
if 'usercode' in session:
    ...

return response
```